# How to get email received event in Android

Tags: android, email, broadcast

I could not find a way to listen email received event. Can any one please suggest me on this.

your valuable suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. 3rd party apps can't access the stock Email applications data.

Comment: yes there is no direct approach available for this but still it is possible in some ways. I seen that "iPhone Notifications" Android app is receiving gmail events

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nlucas.iphonenotificationslite

Comment: @Abilash: First, that Market listing does not mention Gmail. Second, that Market listing describes the hack the developer used.

Answer (score 0):

I could succeed upto an extent, Now I could receive events for any changes happening in gmail account but still i am not clear about how to find only incoming mails.

Note:
I got some hacking techniques for getting this done but it will not work starting from froyo release.

currently I am using below code:
onChange method will get invoked for any changes happening in gmail.

```
mContext.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/unread"), false, GmailObserver(new Handler() {}));

class GmailObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public GmailObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {

            System.out.println("@@@ ContentObserver deliverSelfNotifications");
            return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {

            System.out.println("@@@ ContentObserver onChange");
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        }

    }
```