# How to listen for email messages

Tags: java, android, email, mobile

Is there a way to listen for incoming/outgoing email messages or access the inbox directly?

I read that since there is no default mail client in the Android SDK it is not possible unless the client used on the phone implements some custom mechanisms. Is this still the case?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552768/how-to-get-email-received-event-in-android) answer says no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emails are not part of the Android OS so you cannot code a global Broadcast Receiver (like you would for incoming SMS). The obvious workaround is to code Broadcast Receivers for the top X most popular email clients on Android OS which do broadcast incoming emails.

K9 does give you the flexibility of registering Broadcast Receivers for incoming emails - see https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/wiki/Intents.

Gmail does not have any official / documented API for receiving info about incoming emails. But until a while back, you could make use of Content Observers for monitoring changes to Gmail. I believe this no longer works though.

I think the real issue here is privacy and security. Emails contain much more info compared to SMS. As a user, you really would not want an app ecosystem where third party apps can start monitoring your personal and professional emails.

Comment: +1 for privacy concerns - developers expect to be able to do anything on a phone...

Comment: @cjk - Could not agree more but I think that's why we are developers :-) But seriously, the responsibility is to be shared equally by both - OS manufacturers as well as developers. The current app ecosystem is infact habituating users to download apps and then authorize the downloaded apps to access all sorts of information with a single button touch. I am not even sure if users care to read which all permissions the downloaded app is requesting before they click on the Allow button.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. I understand the motivation to not give access to user's emails. I was just surprised that I am not able to do it since I come from Blackberry development background where this is possible but there is a generic mail app/service by default.