# How to get notified when an email received in android?

Tags: android

Can anyone help me.How to send a notification message while getting an email.How can i know that i have got the email and then generate a message to a phone number in android.

Comment: This can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633698/how-to-listen-for-email-messages You cant have broadcast receiver for email received as it may contain privacy data of user

Comment: Hy thanks..Now i understand the real issue.